How can I access my root directory to save file in ```/etc/environment/```
while setting up java-jkd-22,
I write the code sudo gedit /etc/environment/ in terminal,
after authentication,
I am getting this message
Authorization required, but no authorization protocol specified

(gedit:17210): Gtk-WARNING **: 13:02:15.301: cannot open display: :0

How can I save file to my root directory?

You've not told us what Ubuntu product/release you're using, so we're somewhat limited. Wayland has a higher security approach than old Xorg does, so problems can occur, but if you don't actually have a GUI operational you can't use programs like gedit (You don't actually say if you're using a text only Server, or Desktop, nor what release etc.)
